How can I handle multiple gcc stdc++ configurations in cmake for _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_BACKTRACE?
How can I handle multiple gcc configurations in cmake? The following fails for some releases of ubuntu.
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    target_compile_options(myapp PRIVATE
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG>
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_BACKTRACE>)
    target_link_libraries(myapp $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:stdc++_libbacktrace>) # <-- maybe
endif()


I quite like using _GLIBCXX_DEBUG and _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_BACKTRACE to catch basic out of bounds access. It can be handy for automated testing too.
With gcc 13.2.1 on Fedora 39 (and Ubuntu 20.04) I also need to link with -lstdc++_libbacktrace otherwise I get an error like the following (the docs mention -lstdc++exp but that doesn't work for me):
/usr/bin/ld: ... in function `__gnu_debug::_Error_formatter::_Error_formatter(char const*, unsigned int, char const*)':
/usr/include/c++/13/debug/formatter.h:597: undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_create_state'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/13/debug/formatter.h:598: undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_full'

All good. I'll just link to the extra library. See:

build cpp code with std::backtrace raise err "undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_create_state"
use cpp std::stacktrace raise err "stacktrace’ was not declared in this scope"

The problem happens on Ubuntu 22.04, where I then get:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++_libbacktrace: No such file or directory

I'm rather wildly guessing this is expected. I.e. stdc++_libbacktrace is now part of stdc++ in Ubuntu 22.04 due to being compiled with --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes and not an optional extra library. Whereas the version of gcc packaged for Fedora 39 and Ubuntu 20.04 still need the separate library. Maybe related:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-12/+bug/2048233
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/74782

If this is right, I need to add -lstdc++_libbacktrace but only if the build of gcc that cmake is using was not built with --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes. Can this even be done neatly/portably in cmake?

Most of CMake checks for compiler features is performed via try_compile command and its wrappers. E.g. you could use "Source files" flavor of this command, and pass stdc++_libbacktrace as value of LINK_LIBRARIES parameter. Would this compilation (and linking) attempt succeed, you will know that given library present in the system.

@Tsyvarev thanks! That worked. Just a few lines too, with SOURCE_FROM_CONTENT.
